# Allow only two instances of a character using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to using regular expressions and I am trying to figure out something that would seem to be pretty easy.

I would like to identify if a character exists only twice within a string. The character does not need to be consecutive, but a count of two anywhere in the string. For instance, "41:08:05" is ok, but "41:08" or "41:08:05:02" would not be correct. In this example I am looking for the existence of only two colons (:) anywhere in the string.

I have tried "([:]){2}" but this will only identify consecutive colons.

Comment: You could remove all non-`:` characters: `Regex.Replace(input, @"[^:]", "").Length == 2`

Comment: Do you wish to know if a specific character appears exactly twice or if at least one character appears exactly twice an all other characters appear once or twice? If the later (which is different than the cited duplicate question) you can use the regex `^(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)(?=.*(.).*\2).*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aGHif6/1/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Why so complex suggestions? The answer is as in my already posted answer, just replace `e` with `:`: `^(?:[^:]*:){2}[^:]*$`

Comment: @Wiktor, I was addressing "if at least one character appears exactly twice an all other characters appear once or twice", meaning "if one character in the string (not a specified character) appears exactly twice an all other characters appear once or twice". Keep the suggestions coming, though, as they've been very helpful.

Comment: David, by "if a character exists only twice within a string" do you mean "exactly twice" (as suggested by the fact `41:08` is not a match)? Also, it might be inferred that you are referring to a specific character, `0`, but you do not say that. If you mean at least one character in the string must appear exactly twice, must all other characters appear only once? At most twice? This is the problem of stating a question in terms of examples without explaining why some strings match and others do not. Please clarify by editing (even though the question has been closed).